# How to avoid use casting in an object that has one different value than other keys in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following state and I want to avoid using casting since only one of my object valuse is and array and the rest on bigger scale are

```js
 [key: string]: boolean
```

```js
const inicialErrState: { [key: string]: [boolean, string] | boolean } & {
    double: [boolean, string];
  } = {
 
    double: [false, ""],
    solo1: false,
    solo2: false,
    ... solo10
  };
  
  
  
   <NativeSelectComponent error={err.solo1 as boolean} />
```

Comment: Please consider providing a [mre] suitable to demonstrate your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE.  Right now I don't have `solo10`, `NativeSelectComponent`, or `err` in scope so my IDE just complains about those.  If you do decide to [edit] your code to be a self-contained example and want me to take another look, please comment and mention @jcalz to notify me. Good luck!